# Web part in Quick launch in Team Sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, site, team

I have created a Team Site in Sharepoint 2010 and I want to create a link in the quick launch on the left without being a library or a list, but a webpart page. I dont want to store any documents, but to have an actual page as the home page (without changing the current homepage). Is this possible? Is there a way to have more than one pages with webparts at a team site?

Also, in my Look and Feel menu the "Navigation" link doesnt exist.

I am not myself an experienced programer and I dont have the Sharepoint Designer.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a link to anything in the Quick Launch, if you have the publishing features activated, you see Navigation, otherwise you see quick launch. You can add a link to a web part page with a slew of web parts on it or a link to Google.

Answer (score 0):

To add a link in the quick launch in a team site, Go to Site Settings -> Look And Feel -> Quick Launch. Here you have an option to either create a new Header link or a new navigation link. "Navigation links are embedded in a Header link". So, if you want your web part page to appear as a header, you can click on New Heading and enter the address of the page and the description.  Otherwise, if you want it embedded in some header, you can click on New Navigation Link.

Secondly, in order to set the home page, you can append _layouts/AreaWelcomePage.aspx to the site url. For example, if the site url is `http://aissp2013/sites/Team1`, then change it to `http://aissp2013/sites/Team1/_layouts/AreaWelcomePage.aspx` in the browser. This will open a page where you can select any page in the site to be the home page of the site.